# Where does d3.js search the files

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, svg, d3.js

I'am working with node.js and d3.js. My d3.js script load a csv file. I call this d3.js script from a node.js. I don't know where d3.js search the csv file.

More information about my code is:

The path in the node.js program is:

```
path /home/cloudera/proyecto/nodejs/node-v0.10.17/node_modules/ejemplos
```

The files of this directory are:

```
/home/cloudera/proyecto/nodejs/node-v0.10.17/node_modules/ejemplos
[cloudera@localhost ejemplos]$ ls *.csv
totalbicis1.csv  totalbicis2.csv  totalbicis.csv
```

The code of d3.js

```
d3.csv("totalbicis.csv", type, function(error,data) {
 x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.value; })]);
```

The error message in the browser is

```
GET http://localhost:8000/totalbicis.csv 404 (Not Found) d3.v3.min.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined d3.v3.min.js:3
```

Why don't d3.js find the csv file?

The server-code is

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var d3 = require('d3');
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
ap p.set('views',__dirname);
app.set('view engine','html');

//var fixtureData = require('./fixture_data.json');
//app.locals.barChartHelper = require('./bar_chart_helper');
 app.get('/', function(req, res) {
       console.log('en raiz ');
       var absolute_path = __dirname;
       console.log('path '+absolute_path);
       res.render('grafico1');
       res.end();
 });
app.listen(8000);
```

Thanks your answer

Comment: Can you show your server-side code?

Comment: var express = require('express');
     var app = express();
     var d3 = require('d3');
     app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
    app.set('views',__dirname);
    app.set('view engine','html');

   //var fixtureData = require('./fixture_data.json');
    //app.locals.barChartHelper = require('./bar_chart_helper');
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
       console.log('en raiz ');
        var absolute_path = __dirname;
        console.log('path '+absolute_path);
       res.render('grafico1');
       res.end();
});
app.listen(8000);

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you haven't used `static` middleware (its usage described in the [`app.use` section](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use)).

To fix this error, create a directory (you may call it "static"), and put your .csv files there.
Then add one of these lines to the server-side code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

or

```
app.use('/csv', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

If you choose the second line, you will have to specify `d3.csv("/csv/totalbicis.csv", ...` on the client-side.